# Simple C++ cross-platform way to execute an external program

Tags: c++, cross-platform

What is a simple, elegant, and effective cross-platform way to execute an external program in C++ and get the return code from it?

```cpp
int execute(std::string const &path, std::vector<std::string> const &arguments = {})
{
    //...
}
```

Since we're waiting for the called program to finish before continuing execution, the called program should use our program's input/output/error streams. If, for any number of reasons, `path` isn't executable, just throw an exception (e.g. `std::invalid_argument`).

Obviously, don't use `system()`.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just one single program you need to execute, spawn a worker thread and have that thread call `system`:

```
void executeProgram(std::string programName) {
    system(programName.c_str());
}

void execute() {
    string programName = "test.cpp";
    std::thread worker (executeProgram, programName);
    worker.join(); //wait for the worker to complete
}
```

If you need to be able to spawn many programs, a thread pool class to delegate worker threads and join them upon completion might make more sense.

Comment: Isn't `execvp` *nix-only? This is not a cross-platform solution.

Comment: @LB-- it is, indeed. `system` maybe?

Comment: I think system might be the way to go. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score -1):

At least for command-line applications, I solved this issue using `popen`.On windows is `_popen` but that is easily solved with a define